# Notepad++ color highlight with their value

Tags: notepad++

Last night, last usage of Notepad++, color codes backgrounds were highlighted with their value like below.[image]

But now, background colors are not shown like this.[image]

I did not find settings. Please could you help me, how can I set the settings like first picture?

Answer (score 5):

It's Notepad # ("sharp"). For some reason it can't be "validated" and is disabled after the update. You can go to the link below or download it directly from the Plugin Manager withing N++.

[Link to Notepad#](https://github.com/Lomeli12/Notepad-Sharp)

---

Also,

Try "Quick Color Picker for Notepad++". You double-click on the hex color and a color-picker pops up as well as a preview. Another cool thing is that it provides a few more colors that match the "theme" if you will.

[**Here is the link Quick Color Picker**](https://code.google.com/p/nppqcp/) (it is also available from the Plugin Manager)

Comment: +1 for you ... that Quick Color Picker totally ROCKS. Thank you very much for posting that. I was using, i should say not using, the "Html Color" plugin but i just installed it.

Comment: both links are dead

Comment: There's a forward link, https://github.com/nulled666/nppqcp

Comment: Updated link for Notepad# https://github.com/Lomeli12/Notepad-Sharp

Answer (score 1):

Color highlighting is done by a plugin. I know the Notepad# plugin does it and there might be a few others as well.

During an update the Notepad# plugin was probably disabled.

I noticed it was working on one of my machines but not another. I had to reinstall the Notepad# plugin because the plugin manager was not detecting that there was an update available.

Answer (score 1):

Hello go to plugin manager and select on install the notepad # good luck!

try with the plugin manager

[image]

Comment: The OP asked to colorize the hex color codes. I think NppCalc does not provide that.

Answer (score -1):

From the menu, select `Settings` -> `Style Configurator`.  You should see the following:

[image: NPP Style Settings]

Select `CSS` on the left and then `VALUE` in the middle.  You can then change the `Foreground` and `Background` colors.

Note - I am on Windows, using Notepad++ Version 6.

Comment: I do not want to change background color with any other color. I only want to set CSS hex color codes backgrounds as their values. I think I did not manage telling my problem. If you examine above two pictures, my problem will be understood better enough.

Comment: In the first picture, when we code #c80606, it highlightes its value as nearly red, and when we code #ccc, it highlightes its value as grey.

Comment: @HabipOĞUZ - sorry, I missed that. I cannot find a setting for what you are asking for.