# Which Notepad++ plugin is highlighting my HTML colors?

Tags: colors, notepad++, syntax-highlighting

I have a plugin that I installed that does this:

[image: Notepad++ color highlighting]

I really like this function (highlighting HTML colors) but I don't know plugin does it. I want to put it on the another copy of Notepad++ but installing plugins is a rather big thing and I don't want to have to install them all - it gets cumbersome.

Does anyone know which plugin highlights my colors?
 It's a wonderful feature.

Comment: Oh, I figured it out. It's Notepad#.


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15465917/notepad-color-highlight-with-their-value

Comment: Even so, I'm not sure you'll be able to find that plugin again. You may have to install one of the ones G Siry or I suggested after all. But let us know, I'm eager to find out what you learn!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Notepad++ hover preview on link or color?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14789750/notepad-hover-preview-on-link-or-color)

Answer (score 3):

I think that you are referring to the HTML Color plugin. You can find it here

http://npp.campulka.net/

Comment: Thanks, and nice plugin, but I don't have that one installed. It automagically highlights my colors...hey, waitaminute..it's Notepad#. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

I think that feature was taken out of Notepad++ due to the users' inability to read the text at times if the colors were too overwhelming. Instead, I recommend trying to install the Quick Color Picker or HTML Color plugins. They are about as close as you're going to get:

Quick Color Picker: https://code.google.com/p/nppqcp/

HTML Color: http://npp.campulka.net/

Source: [Notepad++ hover preview on link or color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14789750/notepad-hover-preview-on-link-or-color)

Answer (score 1):

Check [Quick Color Picker for Notepad++](https://github.com/nulled666/nppqcp/).

The plugin puts the colored underline under the color code based on it's value and thus is not obtrusive in reading the text.

I'm using it without any issues with the Notepad++ v6.9.2

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this and resolved it as follows:

Download and install the UDL file found at https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/userDefinedLanguages (get the zip file with all languages). Instructions for installation are on that page. Close Notepad++ and reopen, then go in your Notepad++ menu to "Language". You should now see a long alphabet list with subcategories off to the right indicated by an > Go to H then click on the > and select HTML with your HTML file open in Notepad++ The moment you do that, all your HTML syntax will (should!) be highlighted.